# How can i load a specific section of a website(<td>...</td>) into a UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I've been looking for an answer in other places and questions like mine but found nothing to helpful on the topic. So what im trying to do here is get only a td from a webpage to be loaded into a `UIWebview`. What I have currently is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: hi, could you please elaborate more on your problem. So You want to get all tds and only load them or are you looking for an specific td?

Comment: a specific td on the site

Answer (score 0):

## General solution

If you want to get a part of a website to display somewhere else you are using a technique called scraping.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

## After getting the actual link to scrape:

First you need to find out the XPath. I use the [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org) browser with the [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) add-on to make life easier for me. Now imagine you want the list of physicians on shift. CTRL+click on the cell they are in and select "Inspect with Firebug" (my browser happens to be in Dutch, should be the same icon).

[image]

Now you are in the HTML tab of Firebug and you should see a nested source of the page we're looking at. If you CTRL+click on the TD you want to read and select "copy XPath" you're copying the XPath for that node.

[image]

In this case, it's

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

To get to that node in the Ray Wenderlich tutorial, you need to change

```
// 1
NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials"];

// 3
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='content-wrapper']/ul/li/a";
```

To

```
// 1
NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rmcva.net/"];

// 3
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]";
```

Now I don't know exactly what you want to do with it and ofcourse the example is built around a list of items but you should be able to get results when you step through it with the debugger. Think this should get you started.

Comment: hm ok but can i ask if you might know how to parse a td without it being over complicated, or just in general?

Comment: A HTML document is a nested tree of tags. You need to know where you can find that TD and use the XPath selector to get to it. As Google doesn't seem to contain any TD in it's source I don't have a clue what you really want so I can't give you a specific XPath example. But the tutorial has all the information you need, you just need to apply it to your specific needs.

Comment: Ah sorry i put "google" to cover the sites privacy but yeah ill try and use the site for my specific needs

Comment: Ok well ive been trying and have come to a standstill but heres the website that i need the TD in it's source if you might be able to use that to create an example. www.rmcva.net

Comment: I will try to add some screenshots later but my internet is sl-o-o-o-w-w tonight...